# Application of Kunneth formula to chain maps (Hatcher exercise)

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm working on the following problem from Hatcher, which is in the Kunneth Formula section at the end of the cohomology chapter, and I'm having trouble figuring out where to start. Any direction would be appreciated.

Let $C$ and $C′$ be chain complexes, and let $I$ be the chain complex consisting of $\mathbb{Z}$ in dimension 1 and $\mathbb{Z}$×$\mathbb{Z}$ in dimension 0, with the boundary map taking a generator $e$ in dimension 1 to the difference $v_1$ − $v_0$ of generators $v_i$ of the two $\mathbb{Z}$’s in dimension 0. Show that a chain map $f :I⊗C→C′$ is precisely the same as a chain homotopy between the two chain maps $f_i:C→C′$, $c \rightarrow f(v_i⊗c), i=0,1$. [The chain homotopy is $h(c) = f(e⊗c)$.]

Comment: Try verifying that $h(c) = f(e\otimes c)$ is a chain homotopy between the given chain maps by computing $dh + hd$?

Comment: I did verify the chain homotopy, but I didn't think that was sufficient to show the chain map $f$ was the same as that chain homotopy. Does that get me somewhere though?

Comment: "precisely the same" is a bit vague or a bit too strong. I think the idea is to show there is a bijection between chain maps $I\otimes C \to C'$ and chain homotopies $C\to C'$. So, you have the bijection in one direction, now prove the other: given a chain homotopy $C\to C'$ construct a chain map $I\otimes C \to C'$.